Date & Time range Calendar
Well I have the case where one button would open date and time range calendar in which well both would be able to select. In case of picking second date (range) second time selector would appear, this is rough wireframe.

My question is there some better solution done already ? Note that this action is called from button not from input/date fields

I don't completely understand your question, but I would say one thing. Stick to what already works, for example date&time range calendars used  for booking a plane tickets are doing their job well enough so why over-complicate things? Or is there a specific use case you did not mention?

I don't know of a timestamp-range selection control (as opposed to a date-range selection). The image you provide makes me scratch my head, though - why is the time selection duplicated, and once I understood that, which time selection goes with which date selection? My first guess is that you need a complete overhaul of the design, integrating the time selection into the date calendar to make the association clear.

Can you provide more context about the task? Why the app shows the two time brackets? are those initial time and ending time, for what?

Context is that this FROM - TO date AND time range is used to filter a Chart. Pretty much you click on a button and you need to pick exact date and time (or range) to filter a chart.

With non comprehensive context, use cases and audience, I could help by giving what we have done once in our product.
It was by having a From & To tabs. When user presses the Next on the From tab, the state transitions to To.


Thank you for your insight!

Cool. Does this solve your problem? Can mark as closed in that case.
